# Web2py: Incorrect row when representing a referenced field

Tags: reference, web2py

It's rare that I find an issue that hasn't already be answered but I've been searching for this for 3 days and haven't found anything yet.

I'm aiming to create a page for inputing records in a 'spreadsheet' like format. I've used inline editing in SQLFORM.grid from [this slice](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1928/basic-inline-editing-in-sqlformgrid-no-plugin-no-javascript).

The problem I'm having is that when one of the fields is a reference to another table, the row being use in the lambda function is taking the row of the reference table rather than the row in the grid.

Here is an example:
**Model**

```
db.define_table('people',
            Field('name', 'string'),
            format = '%(name)s',
            )

db.define_table('animals',
            Field('name', 'string'),
            Field('pet_owner', 'reference people'),
            format = '%(name)s',
            )
```

**Controller**

```
def index():
    #process submitted form
    if len(request.post_vars) > 0:
        print request.post_vars
        for key, value in request.post_vars.iteritems():
            (field_name,sep,row_id) = key.partition('_row_')
            if row_id:
                db(db.animals.id == row_id).update(**{field_name:value})

    db.animals.name.represent = lambda value,row:  SQLFORM.widgets.string.widget(db.animals.pet_owner,value, **{'_name':'name_row_%s' % row.id})

    db.animals.pet_owner.represent = lambda value,row:  SQLFORM.widgets.options.widget(db.animals.pet_owner,value, **{'_name':'pet_owner_row_%s' % row.id})

    grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.animals,
                        selectable= lambda ids : redirect(URL('animals',vars=request._get_vars)),
                        )
    grid.elements(_type='checkbox',_name='records',replace=None)  #remove selectable's checkboxes
    return dict(grid=grid)
```

At first it appears that the grid is working correctly. However, when inspecting the drop-downs for the reference fields, if two consecutive rows have the same value (e.g. two animals with the same owner) the same row is used in the name (pet_owner_row_1) which means that the value being passed to process the submitted form is not an integer (e.g. 3) but as the integers separated by pipes (e.g. '|3|3|').

I've confirmed that this is where the issue is by changing the represent to 
    db.animals.pet_owner.represent = lambda value,row: row
which shows the exact same row data for different animals.

Here is an image showing the inspector on the form items: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFtF8.png

How can I get the row id of the grid's row rather than the id of the reference?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has recently been [fixed](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/commit/8420020c215d79f7855d8f92c97dbb0ad27bd977) in the master branch but not released yet. In the meantime, a workaround is to temporarily change the field to an integer type:

```
db.animals.pet_owner.type = 'integer'
db.animals.pet_owner.represent = lambda value,row: SQLFORM.widgets.options.widget(
    db.animals.pet_owner,value, **{'_name':'pet_owner_row_%s' % row.id})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I've cloned from the master branch and it's now working as expected. Annoying that I spent so much time trying to solve it but also relieving to know that I hadn't done anything wrong.